# Attempting to make a simple iterative calculation with a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to setup a simple for loop calculation in R whereby a dataframe is populated with calculated values.

Here is the gist of it:
- I have a dataframe that is 10 columns wide and 30 rows long; the columns are vectors of simulated returns, the rows are days of a month.
- I have another dataframe of the same size, where the first row is stock prices at today's date, and all other rows are empty.
- I simply want to iteratively fill the rest of the second dataframe with calculated prices using the given starting price and the simulated returns in the first dataframe, using a basic formula like this:

Price(today) = Price(yesterday) * (1 + Simulated Return(today))

Here is an example:

```
## This makes a 30x10 dataframe of random simulated returns
ret = replicate(10, rnorm(30, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.25))

## This makes the empty 30x10 dataframe where prices will go
pri = ret
pri[] = NA

## This fills the first row of the second dataframe with given values (today's price)
given = replicate(10, 1234)
pri[1,] = given
```

After this point is where I run into problems with designing a correct for-loop. I am unsure of how to structure the syntax to make this iterate so that for each empty row in the second dataframe the empty cells are filled one by one, based on the corresponding values of returns at time (t) in the first dataframe, and the price of the prior time period (t-1) in the second dataframe, using the basic formula I have described above.

The idea I was going for was something like

```
pri[2,] = pri[1,] * (1 + ret[2,])
```

but for all of the remaining rows in the second dataframe in succession (rows 2:30, segregated by column). Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: r has actual `array`s. these sounds like `data.frame`s. helping wld be easier if you used the proper terms or indicated you are, indeed, actually using arrays. the distinction matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function based solution using `sapply` is explained below. The logic is to populate price matrix with simulated returns factors and populate the 1st row with today's price. `sapply` will take 1 column at a time and perform the calculation based on `Price(today) = Price(yesterday) * (1 + Simulated Return(today))` and return value of that column,

```
## This makes a 30x10 dataframe of random simulated returns. 
## Notice I have changed it to data.frame
ret = data.frame(replicate(10, rnorm(30, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.25))

## This makes the empty 30x10 dataframe where prices will go
pri = ret
## pri[] = NA -- no need. Let the factor be available for dates.

## This fills the first row of the second dataframe with given values (today's price)
given = replicate(10, 1234)
pri[1,] = given

# Function that performs calculation on simulated price based on previous day
poputate_value <- function(x){
  for(i in 2:length(x)){
    x[i] <- x[i-1] * (1 + x[i])
  }
  x
}

# Function will be applied on all columns and value will be returned to result
result <- sapply(pri, poputate_value)

## > head(result)

           X1       X2        X3       X4        X5       X6        X7        X8        X9       X10
[1,] 1234.000 1234.000 1234.0000 1234.000 1234.0000 1234.000 1234.0000 1234.0000 1234.0000 1234.0000
[2,] 1038.855 1580.027  991.9454 1975.709 1447.9575 1733.466  856.0908  928.6600 1119.1489 1011.4543
[3,] 1113.040 1411.237  807.3748 1791.978 1333.1235 1957.516  972.3401  874.6964 1133.1161 1095.7755
[4,] 1242.637 1104.528  906.7417 1443.040  944.8004 2198.782 1242.2810 1314.4354 1722.6803 1478.0986
[5,] 1822.834 1224.279 1245.4425 1381.826 1295.5291 2887.676 1349.2818 1367.2311  908.4315  780.4360
[6,] 1690.193 1218.778  883.5074 2126.224 1340.3102 2994.756 1542.1661 1300.4834  998.1949  702.0578
```